# $(3y^2+4y)y'+2x+\cos x=0;\; y(0)=1$. Solve the initial value problem

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

information

> $(3y^2+4y)y'+2x+\cos x=0 ;\; y(0)=1$.
>
> Solve the initial value problem

I am stuck at $$y^3+2y^2=-x^2+\sin x+c$$ how do  I isolate y

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Find $c$ by using the initial condition.

As for isolating $y,$ you don't need that. It suffices to leave $y$ to be implicitly defined. Many times, this is what obtains. In fact, this is even better since most times you cannot get a closed form at all.